# How to run USSD from background with out showing up the dialog

Tags: android

I want to make an app that automatically run USSD code from background without showing the user the dialog interface and give confirmation for the ussd response

FOR EXAMPLE: when i want to buy internet package i have to call *804# then i have to confirm by entering 1 so my question is....how can i give confirmation for ussd response ?

```
String ussdCode = "*" + "123" + Uri.encode("#");
startActivity(new Intent(Intent.ACTION_CALL, Uri.parse("tel:" + ussdCode)));
```

Comment: So you want an App to spend the users money without the users consent?

Comment: that should be impossible due to you should not be able to spend users' money without their confirmation.